# Write the UIView Hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiview-hierarchy

I’m trying to write a text file with name of all the views contains in the Screen. For example 
I have a `UIView` in which I have 2 `UIButtons` so the file should be as bellow..

```
UIWindow
    UIView
        UIButton
            UIButtonLabel
        UIButton
            UIButtonLabel
        _UILayoutGuide
        _UILayoutGuide
```

This is how I'm trying to do but the above hierarchy I'm unable to achieve.

```
-(void) writeViewHierarchyForView:(UIView *)aView inString:( NSMutableString *)str
{
    //NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"title Text = %@", aView.titleText);
    if(nil == aView.children){
        [str appendString:@"\n"];
        return;
    }
    else{
        for(UIView *view in aView.subview){
            [str appendString:@"\n\t"];
            [str appendString:view.name];
            NSLog(@"%@",view.name);
            [str appendString:@"\t"];
            [self writeViewHierarchyForView:view inString:str];
        }
    }
}
```

this is not something I'm using in any project but doing it just for fun.
any suggestion would be great.

Comment: for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) {...}  this way u would get all subviews in a single view. So as u move from one view to another search about these subview and do perform ur operation

Comment: @walle84 problem is not to get subview, I know we already have methods for that. but the problem is to dump those subview names in to a text file, according to hierarchy level (mention in question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably won't be able to submit apps to the app store using the following code (which it sounds like you don't want anyways) since it's undocumented private API, but you can use this in your debugging:

`NSLog(@"%@", [self.view valueForKey:@"recursiveDescription"]);`

you can also use `recursiveDescription` in the LLDB console for debugging when you're on a breakpoint:

`po [someView recursiveDescription]`

Comment: Yeah, I'm not going to submit any app with this code and this is something I'm looking for..thank you.